# How to modify an optional field of a struct in a member function

Tags: rust

I have a structure `Struct` that optionally contains `SubStruct`. `SubStruct` contains a field. 
I would like to call the `modify` member method of `Struct`, that calls the `modify_field` member method of `SubStruct` that modifies the `field` field of `SubStruct`

This is different from other questions mentioned, as it is not modifying the field directly, but calling a member method that in turn modifies the field. Modifying the field directly has a shared solution I have seen.

```
struct SubStruct {
    field: u32,
}

impl SubStruct {
    fn modify_field(&mut self) {
       self.field = 2
    }
}

struct Struct {
    sub: Option<SubStruct>,
}

impl Struct {
    fn modify(&mut self) {
        if let Some(ref mut sub) = self.sub { // no reference before Some
            sub.modify_field();

            self.do_something();
        }
    }

    fn do_something(&self) {
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sub = Some(SubStruct{field: 1});
    let mut structure = Struct{ sub };

    structure.modify();

    println!("{}", structure.sub.unwrap().field);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b93df4f62c27abdf33461244d3008c65&version=stable)

I've tried many variants with no luck, with my current version I am stuck with this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because `self.sub.0` is also borrowed as mutable
--> src/main.rs:20:13
   |
17 |         if let Some(ref mut sub) = self.sub { // no reference before Some
   |                          ----------- mutable borrow occurs here 
... 
20 |             self.do_something();    
   |             ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
21 |         }    |         - mutable borrow ends here
```

As you can see, it  seems to be related to `self.do_something()` taking an immutable borrow of `self`, where a mutable borrow of `self` was already taken in the function parameter.

Comment: *as it is not modifying the field directly, but calling a member method that in turn modifies the field* — The example used in the duplicate (addition) **is** a method, specifically the [`AddAssign` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html).

Comment: OK, so as ljedrez mentions below, I basically need to refactor to avoid this?

Comment: Additionally, it's [frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254521/155423) to change your question, especially after it's been answered (and accepted!).

Comment: The duplicate message specifically asked me to: "modify your question to clarify how it is different to others" (duplicates) and the previous edits by others had changed the error message from playground, and that didn't coincide with the code.... so I corrected it back.

Comment: I copied the [**exact code you pasted here**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47589295/1) into the playground, ran it, then copied the generated errors back into the question. I cannot help that the code you pasted wasn't what you meant it to be, if they differed somehow. Your *original* code and error message didn't coincide, which I fixed. Anyway, I've now marked this as a duplicate of some of the many "also borrowed" questions.

Comment: Additionally, if the question you originally asked was answered, but then you discovered that you didn't ask the right question, you *ask another question*. Look at how the **accepted** answer seemingly "ignores" half of your question. The edits make the answerer look really poor, even though they answered your original question perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
impl Struct {
    fn modify(&mut self) {
        if let Some(ref mut sub) = self.sub { // no reference before Some
            sub.modify_field();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sub = Some(SubStruct { field: 1 });
    let mut structure = Struct { sub };

    structure.modify(); // no arguments, we are only working on self

    println!("{}", structure.sub.unwrap().field);
}
```

When you are mutably borrowing `structure` with `modify(&mut self)`, `self.sub` is still an `Option<SubStruct>`, so destructuring it with an `if let` binding yields `Some(sub)`. Since you are only mutably borrowing `self`, though, you need to prevent the move of the `Option`'s contents with `ref mut` (as you did).

Comment: Thanks! That solves the example so I have accepted answer. Now let me try and apply it to my own real (more complex example).....

Comment: I was afraid so, my simplified example was too simplified.... I want to call another method of Struct and it gives the error: "error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because `self.sub.0` is also borrowed as mutable" I have updated the playground code.. 
https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=93bf23c21a3a54687700f1d1a66ea3c1&version=stable

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie you won't be able to immutably borrow `self` in the block under that `if let` binding (i.e. while a mutable borrow is in force); you could do it just outside it, though, as long as that works for your original code. If it doesn't, I recommend filing a new question with a bit more of the original code.

Comment: Thanks, I feared that and don't see an easy workaround. The code now in the playground effectively reproduces the problem - without all my messiness I you are interested. I guess I'll need to rethink that code... :-(

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie to be honest, it doesn't look like it needs heavy refactoring - even if this is represents the problem, some additional code could help suggest some possible solutions.

Comment: thanks for the help and offer of more. I created a new question that I hope captures the problem better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618162/how-to-call-a-member-method-while-inside-block-with-mutable-reference-to-self