# How to call a member method while inside block with mutable reference to self

Tags: rust

`Flow` has a member method (`change_conn_routes()`) that modifies its contents, so it needs a `&mut self` reference.

To function, this method needs to call another member method (`get_port()`) that doesn't modify anything, so has a `&self` reference. This won't compile.

```
struct Conn {
    name: String,
    route: String,
}

struct Flow {
    conns: Option<Vec<Conn>>,
    port: String
}

impl Flow {
    // This method does not modify anything so if possible I'd like it to not
    // need a mutable reference to self.
    fn get_port(&self, _name: &str) -> String {
        // In real program the value of name is actually used - simplified here
        format!("{}", self.port)
    }

    // This method changes the contents of self.conns so reference to self must
    // be mutable. To do so, it needs information from another member function of self
    fn change_conn_routes(&mut self) {
        if let Some(ref mut conns) = self.conns {
            for conn in conns {
                conn.route = format!("{}", self.get_port(&conn.name));
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let conns = Some(vec!(Conn{ route: "abc".to_string(), name: "conn1".to_string() }));
    let port = "123".to_string();
    let mut flow = Flow{ conns, port };

    flow.change_conn_routes();

    println!("{}", flow.conns.unwrap()[0].route);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dd8adc091aad2b8ae557818e26a33160&version=nightly)

Leads to this compiler error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (file:///playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because `self.conns.0` is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:24:44
   |
22 |         if let Some(ref mut conns) = self.conns {
   |                     ------------- mutable borrow occurs here
23 |             for conn in conns {
24 |                 conn.route = format!("{}", self.get_port(&conn.name));
   |                                            ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
25 |             }
26 |         }
   |         - mutable borrow ends here
```

Comment: If you are having trouble adopting the solution from the duplicate, I didn't mind doing it in [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=106be1e3cd959f3c343a3ba7247ecfab&version=stable).

Comment: I think the case is the inverse (I iterate over mutable field - self.conns- , and make a call to a method that is immutable - get_port() - ) - but the issue is the same I guess?

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice you did it already! Thanks a lot! Pity I can't upvote your efforts... thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it was exactly a duplicate case either, but I am pretty lax about them; no worries, I'm glad I could help :).

Comment: In addition (I forgot to mention it yesterday), you could consider if wrapping that `Vec<Conn>` in an `Option` is necessary; in this case an empty vector could represent the same case as `None`.

Comment: Yeh, I was looking at that and that's how I would have written it - but it all comes from a serde_derived deserialization of toml - and it has an optional (array) of tables....so I think it's required to let it deserialize directly.